# NodeJS file stream - how to create a file if it doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, plotly

I'm trying to get my head around the Plotly library for Node JS.  I've been looking at some of the examples on https://github.com/plotly/plotly-nodejs.  I need to be able to save an image of a plot, so that this image can then be displayed to the user, rather than them having to go to a separate website and view the file.  There isn't really much in the way of documentation for this (or at least I haven't been able to find any!) so I'm flying blind.

I've created a module called charts.js to try and test this, as follows:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const plotly = require('plotly')(<username>, <api_key>);

const self = module.exports = {

plotChart: function()
{
    let data = [
    {
        x:[0,1,2],
        y:[3,2,1],
        type: 'bar'
    }];

    let layout = {
        fileopt : "overwrite",
        filename : "simple-node-example"
    };

    plotly.plot(data, layout, function (err, msg)   /** @namespace plotly.plot */
    {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(msg);
    });
},

writeImage: function()
{
    let trace1 = {
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
        type: "scatter"
    };

    let figure = {
        'data': [trace1]
    };

    let imgOpts = {
        format: 'png',
        width: 1000,
        height: 500
    };

    plotly.getImage(figure, imgOpts, function (error, imageStream)
    {
            if (error)
            {
                return console.log (error);
            }

            let fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./public/charts/test.png');
            imageStream.pipe(fileStream);
        });
    }
};
```

When I'm testing my app, I use the following command to try and write an image:

```
charts.writeImage();
```

When I do this, nothing happens.  I check my logs (via Heroku) and I see the following error:

```
2018-03-28T14:01:01.224962+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:183
2018-03-28T14:01:01.224966+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-03-28T14:01:01.224968+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-03-28T14:01:01.224969+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-03-28T14:01:01.224971+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './public/charts/test.png'
2018-03-28T14:01:01.285729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-03-28T14:01:01.287554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-28T14:01:01.275663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Am I correct in guessing that this error happens because the target file doesn't exist?  If so, how do I create this file programmatically?

Comment: Try [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#methods)'s `ensureFile` or `ensureDir`. Although it could be a permission issue too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer required as I found [ImageCharts](https://image-charts.com/) to be better suited to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file inside the if condition.

```
if (err.contains("no such file") {
        fs.write(filename, data, encoding, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```